# Using labels like HTML5 placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

I am trying to use `<label>` elements in my html contact form like the HTML5 placeholder attribute for inputs. I have written the following JavaScript to to act as a reusable function witch will provide the following functionality.

1. Find the input by name.
2. Get the value of the input.
3. Find the label belonging to the input.
4. Change the label style depending on the state of the input.
5. Change the label style depending on the value of the input.

However it is not working and I don't know why as no errors appear in the console. What am I doing wrong? [here is a JS Fiddle with code](http://jsfiddle.net/cCxjk/3/)

```js
function placeholder(field_name) {

    // Get the input box with field_name 
    // Then get input value
    var box = document.getElementsByName(field_name);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        var value = document.getElementById(box[i].value);
    }

    // Get the labels belonging to each box using the HTML for attribute
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('LABEL');
    for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        if (labels[i].htmlFor !== '') {
            var elem = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
            if (elem) {
                box.label = labels[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // Colors
    var focusColor = "#D5D5D5";
    var blurColor = "#B3B3B3";

    // If no text is in the box then show the label grey color
    box.onblur = function () { 
        box.label.style.color = blurColor; 
    };

    // If input focuses change label color to light grey
    box.onfocus = function () { 
        box.label.style.color = focusColor; 
    };

    // If there is text in the box then hide the label
    if (box.value !== "") {
        // Quick do something, hide!
        box.label.style.color = "transparent";
    }
}

// Call the function passing field names as parameters
placeholder(document.getElementsByName("email"));
placeholder(document.getElementsByName("firstName"));
placeholder(document.getElementsByName("lastName"));
```

Comment: Now how you are comparing `label` and `placeholders`?

Comment: `var box = document.getElementsByName(field_name);` - `box` is a _NodeList_. `if (elem) box.label = labels[i];` Setting new property _label_ on _NodeList_. Furthermore, `var` inside loops makes me sad.

Comment: @PaulS. What exactly is he doing here? he fetches the placeholder values but for what? `placeholder(document.getElementsByName("email"));`

Comment: you are inserting arrays in simple variables, how you expect this to work?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Looks like he wants to permanently make a `<label>` change to `visibility: hidden;` if the value of the element referenced by it's _for_ is not `""` when `placeholder` is called.

Comment: @PaulS. god knows, as he is not replying

Comment: @Mr.Alien sorry late reply, new to this :)

Comment: If it is not clear what I am trying to do here is a list:
1. Find the input by name.
2. Get the value of the input.
3. Find the label belonging to the input.
4. Change the label style depending on the state of the input.
5. Change the label style depending on the value of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be considered a little overkill on the number of listeners I've used, feel free to remove any you think unnecessary, but I've tried to employ your HTML structure as you have it and give you all desired effects. It should work for either the `<label>`s *for* matching the `<input>`s *id* OR matching it's `<name>` (given no *id* matches). I'll always say prefer using an *id* over *name*. I believe this *JavaScript* should also work in all browsers too, except the `addEventListener` for which you'd need a shim for old IE versions (let me know if it doesn't in one/the error message).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFQY9/2/)

```
var focusColor = "#D5D5D5", blurColor = "#B3B3B3";
function placeholder(fieldName) {
    var named = document.getElementsByName(fieldName), i;
    for (i = 0; i < named.length; ++i) { // loop over all elements with this name
        (function (n) { // catch in scope
            var labels = [], tmp, j, fn, focus, blur;
            if ('labels' in n && n.labels.length > 0) labels = n.labels; // if labels provided by browser use it
            else { // get labels from form, filter to ones we want
                tmp = n.form.getElementsByTagName('label');
                for (j = 0;j < tmp.length; ++j) {
                    if (tmp[j].htmlFor === fieldName) {
                        labels.push(tmp[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (j = 0; j < labels.length; ++j) { // loop over each label
                (function (label) { // catch label in scope
                    fn = function () {
                        if (this.value === '') {
                            label.style.visibility = 'visible';
                        } else {
                            label.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        }
                    };
                    focus = function () {
                        label.style.color = focusColor;
                    };
                    blur = function () {
                        label.style.color = blurColor;
                    };
                }(labels[j]));
                n.addEventListener('click', fn); // add to relevant listeners
                n.addEventListener('keydown', fn);
                n.addEventListener('keypress', fn);
                n.addEventListener('keyup', fn);
                n.addEventListener('focus', fn);
                n.addEventListener('focus', focus);
                n.addEventListener('blur', fn);
                n.addEventListener('blur', blur);
            }
        }(named[i]));
    }
};
placeholder("email"); // just pass the name attribute
placeholder("firstName");
placeholder("lastName");
```

Comment: This is awesome! I've been trying to solve this on and off for the last week. It works in all browsers I care about, and IE9. Thank you for you work.

Comment: Just be aware that this method creates 3 functions per `<label>` per `<input>` with that name, so if you've a lot of forms which have `<input>`s with matching _name_, each with labels etc, you could end up with **lots** of functions floating around out there.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cCxjk/5/

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var old_ele = '';
var old_label ='';
function hide_label(ele){
    var id_of_input = ele.target.id;
    var label = document.getElementById(id_of_input + '-placeholder');

    if(ele.target == document.activeElement){
        label.style.display = 'none';    
    }
    if (old_ele.value == '' && old_ele != document.activeElement){
        old_label.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    old_ele = ele.target;
    old_label = label;
    }

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', hide_label);
}
```

I will point out a couple things, you will have to find away around the fact that the `label` is inside the `input` so users now can't click on half of the `input` and actually have the `input` gain `focus`.

Also I guess you want to do this in IE (otherwise I would strongly advise using the html5 placeholder!) which means you would need to change the `ele.target` to `ele.srcElement`.

Comment: Ah thanks @ryan that's a great way of getting the label. Brilliant. I didn't realise that I had already set the id of the labels up like that. :)